# What is the difference in usage between [問]{と}い[合]{あ}わせ and [依]{い}[頼]{らい}

Tags: word-choice, nuances

Both 問い合わせ and 依頼　can mean to ask, but my co-workers are using both words in the application we are working on as if they are two different words.

I have a suspicion one is transitive and one is intransitive in their usage, but not entirely sure.

Edit: From the comments an enquiry and a request are both asking for information. That is where i was getting confused.

Comment: I dunno, "enquiry" and "request" seem pretty different to me...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two words mean different things. They just happen to be different things that can sometimes be represented by a single English word.

`問い合わせ` is a request for information. You often see it used for customer support phone numbers you can call if you have questions about the product you just bought.

`依頼` is a request for someone to do something (such as provide you with a service), often also translated as "commision". It's the word you use if you ask a lawyer to represent you, hire a freelance design firm to make you a web page, etc.